# Value not displayed for [HiddenInput] in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model property:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

When I display the property, nothing is shown:

```
@Html.Display("MyProperty")
```

Note that as this is for display, I'm not attempting to use:

```
@Html.Editor("MyProperty")
```

It shows the value if I use:

```
@Html.Value("MyProperty")
```

...but this bypasses the DisplayTemplates.

I'm guessing that the MVC rendering logic has something to stop displaying values with my aforementioned `[HiddenInput]` attribute, but if I wanted to do that explicitly I would use `[ShowForDisplay(false)]`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The `Display` function "Returns HTML markup for each property in the object that is represented by a string expression" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174(v=vs.98).aspx).

What this means is that if your field is a hidden one it will indeed spit out the markup, but because the markup is that of a hidden field you won't see anything directly on the page. You will get something along the lines of `<input type="hidden" value="your value" />`. If you look in the page code you will see that the markup is there.

If you want to display just a value on your page, you can simply do `@Model.Property`. If you want to input the value into a control you can call any one of many `@Html`-based controls and input `Model.Property` as the default value.

Personally, I don't like the idea of defining how a page should look in a model. For me, the value itself should be managed by the model but how it is displayed should be left up to your view itself.

---

I understand that you are working with a display and not an input view here. Regardless of that though, the `HiddenInput` attribute simply states that when an editor is rendered for the field (such as with `@Html.EditorFor()`), it should be a hidden input HTML element. If you are not trying to render an editor then this attribute has no bearing on the result and you can simply do `@Model.Property` to render the element onscreen as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misread my question.  This is a display view, not an edit view (I did mention that).  I don't see why an editor attribute, such as [HiddenInput] should affect display.  The HTML that is returned by the Display function is, in this case, zilch.

Comment: Thanks again, but I can't do that.  This is a generic screen and I can only render the property by name.  Also, I need to add some additional view data for a display template to use, so I am reliant on the Html.Display function.

Comment: Render the property by name?

Comment: Yes, as in @Html.Display(expression: "MyProperty")

Comment: Rendering by name is bad practice because it is weakly-typed. Instead you should use a strongly-typed view that takes an interface as a model and then implement the interface in all models which can be served to the view. This will allow strong-typing in your view, which is one of the huge advantages of ASP.NET MVC 3+.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just [HiddenInput] instead of [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]. This will automatically show the field on display and edit as a label. Hope this helps.